# How can I reverse proxy my API requests with nginx?

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

To add some context:

I'm running an Angular PWA with Node.js backend.
They run on different ports:

· Front-end: Hosted by nginx on port 80

· Back-end: Hosted by Node.js on port 3939

nginx is within a Docker container.

---

Thing is, I plan to redirect all traffic related to /api from port 80 to port 3939 internally via reverse proxy. I'm testing with /api/agenda to see if it works, but it isn't.

Here's the default.conf file I'm using:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /api/agenda {
                proxy_pass   http://localhost:3939;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

I'm testing with Postman to see if redirect works, but I'm getting a 404 while accessing with this url:
http://localhost:80/api/agenda

If I access it using its original port, I do get the desired results, but that's not what I want to do.
http://localhost:3939/api/agenda

---

**Edit:** Here's the error logs I get in my docker console when I try to access http://localhost:80/api/agenda

```
1 | 172.19.0.1 - - [22/Jun/2022:07:13:50 +0000] "GET /api/agenda HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"

nginx-conf-web-1 | 2022/06/22 07:55:18 [error] 28#28: *8 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /api/agenda HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3939/api/agenda", host: "localhost:80"
```

---

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you add a slash at the end of `proxy_pass http://localhost:3939/;`? Let me know if it works

Comment: You should use a docker Node.js container name instead of `localhost` in `proxy_pass` directive.

Comment: @IvanShatsky but my Node.js is not within a container. It is running on local machine

Comment: What's the matter to keep nginx in a container therefore? Read the [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) SO thread too.

Comment: @JuanFontes I tried and it outputs same error. Also tried with entire route, like http://localhost:3939/api/agenda and it also doesn't work

Comment: @Aleen I've noticed that you are running your app on your local machine, you need to put your local IP in Nginx conf, or follow the doc that Ivan sent. By local IP I mean 192.168.. or 10.0.. it depends on how your network is set up. The issue is: Nginx is trying to pass the requests to the 3939 port in nginx container.

Comment: @IvanShatsky The URL host.docker.internal did the trick for me. If you place this in an answer, I'll gladly mark it as the solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JuanFontes I figured that much. host.docker.internal worked for me. Thank you both for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the comments worked for me, regarding @Ivan Shatsky.

Switching: "https://localhost:port/api
to: https://host.docker.internal:port/api

Thank you to the people in the comments.